# PHP HTML input tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

Im trying to make a bar that displays the user that is logged in using php and cookies. But if no cookie is found display 2 buttons that say sign in or sign up

Here is the php

```
<?php
            if ($_COOKIE['user']){
                echo $_COOKIE['user'];
                echo "<input type='button' id='signout-button' class='submit' value='Sign out' onclick='window.location = 'signout.php''>";
            } else {
                echo "<input type='button' id='signup-button' class='submit' value='Sign up' onclick='window.location = 'signup.php''>";
                echo "<input type='button' id='signin-button' class='submit' value='Sign in' onclick='window.location = 'signin.php''>";
           }
       ?>
```

But when I click the button it doesn't go anywhere the source code of the elements looks like this

```
<input type="button" id="signout-button" class="submit" value="Sign out" onclick="window.location = " signout.php''="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoting is off, e.g.:

```
echo "<input type='button' id='signout-button' class='submit' value='Sign out' onclick='window.location = 'signout.php''>";
//                                                                                                        ^           ^
```

Those should be escaped, or use HTML mode so that you can use double quotes for JavaScript strings:

```
?>
<input type='button' id='signout-button' class='submit' value='Sign out' onclick='location.href = "signout.php"'>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use different quotes, for e.g. you code should look like

```
<input type="button" id="signout-button" class="submit" value="Sign out" onclick="window.location = 'signout.php'">
```

but the best option for you, will be to create this buttons with proper tag <a></a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.location.href` and you need to escape your string using `\` so:

```
<?php
            if ($_COOKIE['user']){
                echo $_COOKIE['user'];
                echo "<input type='button' id='signout-button' class='submit' value='Sign out' onclick='window.location.href = \"signout.php\"'>";
            } else {
                echo "<input type='button' id='signup-button' class='submit' value='Sign up' onclick='window.location.href = \"signup.php\"'>";
                echo "<input type='button' id='signin-button' class='submit' value='Sign in' onclick='window.location.href = \"signin.php\"'>";
           }
       ?>
```